# Why does the custom condition for pagination in wordpress not work?

Tags: php, wordpress

My task is to display 6 posts on the first page of the pagination, and then 9. Pagination on the category page of the form category-news.php .

Here is my code in functions.php:

```
function limit_posts_per_home_page() 
{
  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

  $first_page_limit = 6;
  $limit = get_option('posts_per_page');
  

  if( is_admin() ) {
    return;
  }


  if ( is_category('6') )
  { 
    if ($paged == 1)
    {
      $limit = $first_page_limit;
    }
    else
    {
      $offset = $first_page_limit + (($paged - 3) * $limit);
      set_query_var('offset', $offset);   
    }
  }

  set_query_var('posts_per_archive_page', $limit);
  set_query_var('posts_per_page', $limit);
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'limit_posts_per_home_page');
```

But it doesn't work. I see the same number of posts on pagination pages that are set in the settings.
All conditions are met. After the last condition(if ($paged == 1)), I see the correct value $limit=6. it turns out the error is somewhere here set_query_var And I don't quite understand how to melt it here

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Why not start your debugger to step through the execution of this code?

Comment: @NicoHaase All conditions are met. After the last condition(if ($paged == 1)), I see the correct value $limit.
it turns out the error is somewhere here 
set_query_var
And I don't quite understand how to melt it here

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Don't use the comment section for clarification

Comment: `pre_get_posts` is an action, not a filter.  [pre_get_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) you want to use setters.